# How to generate config file from oslo.config?

Tags: openstack, oslo

OpenStack uses oslo.config to define config file options. oslo.config defines configure name, default value, help message, group etc. Since help message is also defined in code, I'm guessing there should be a way to generate a configure file from olso.config.CONF.

Dose anybody knows about that?